# One on one mapping between texels and screen pixels in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am doing the following with OpenGL. My screen is of size 512*512. I have a texture of the same size as the screen. I want to draw a quad that covers the whole screen and establishes a one on one mapping between pixels and texels, so that I can do `texelFetch` with screen coordinates in shaders.

First, if I setup the corners of the quad like the following:

```
(-1, 1)+-----------+(1,1)
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
(-1,-1)+-----------+(1,-1)
```

and set their corresponding texture coordinates as:

```
(0,511)+-----------+(511,511)
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
(0,  0)+-----------+(511,0)
```

I just got a white screen using the following fragment shader which tries to assign different colors to its four boundaries:

```
#version 330

in vec2 fUV;                              // sent from vertex shader

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    if (fUV.x == 0)                       // leftmost
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else if (fUV.y == 0)                  // bottom
        color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else if (fUV.x == 511)                // rightmost
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else if (fUV.y == 511)                // top
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else                                  // otherwise
        color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // check if uv equals an integer
    if (fUV.y == 100)
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

which means all equality test have failed.

Secondly, If I add a half pixel width offset `d= 1.0 / 512` to all -1 coordinates:

```
(-1+d, 1 )+-----------+(1,1)
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
(-1+d,-1+d)+-----------+(1,-1+d)
```

keeping other things unchanged, I got the leftmost red line drawn on the screen.

The above results I got are really confusing. Why was only the leftmost column drawn while the bottom row was not?

I would like to know how should I draw a quad and set their coordinates so that I can establish a one on one mapping between pixels and texels.

Comment: You shouldn't do floating point comparison with `==` operator.  Use `abs(fUV.x - 511) < 0.001`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misinterpret pixels as points. OpenGL, by default, treats them as squares with half-integer coordinates at the centers. That means that if you submit the following texture coordinates:

```
(0,511)+-----------+(511,511)
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
       |           |
(0,  0)+-----------+(511,0)
```

then the bottom right fragment at screen coordinates `(511, 0)` will be sampled at `(511.5, 0.5)`, and will get the texture coordinates interpolated giving `(510.501, 0.499023)`.

There are a few ways to achieve your goal.

1. Use the following texture coordinates and truncate:

   ```
   (0,512)+-----------+(512,512)
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
          |           |
   (0,  0)+-----------+(512,0)
   ```

   Now interpolating the coordinates at `(511.5, 0.5)` gives `(511.5, 0.5)`, and truncating to integers gives `(511, 0)`, which is the coordinates of the pixel for `texelFetch`.
2. Use `gl_FragCoord.xy` instead of texture coordinates. It contains the same numbers as the interpolated texture coordinates in the previous item.
3. Use normalized [0,1] texture coordinates and `texture` instead of `texelFetch` for lookup:

   ```
   (0,1)+-----------+(1,1)
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
   (0,0)+-----------+(1,0)
   ```

   If your viewport is exactly of the same size as the texture then *this will* establish an exact mapping between pixels and texels.

   This approach is the most flexible and I highly recommend it to the others.